# jQuery, Combine contents of classes and remove old class entries

Tags: html, jquery

Using jQuery (which I am just learning) I want to take the contents of the product-price class, as well as the product-color class, and combine them with the product-title class contents. I would like these old classes be removed or hidden. It looks like the code works for the first product as I get the result that I want, but not the second product:

Product 1 ($20, Blue)

Product 2 (undefined, undefined)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    var i = 0;
  console.log(i);
    while( i <= $('.product-title').length)
  {
 
    var value1 = $(".product-price span")[i];
    var value2 = $(".product-color span")[i];
 
    
  $(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(' \(', value1, '\,', value2, '\)')
  /*$(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(value2);*/
 
  i = i + 1;
  console.log(i);
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="catalog-courses" class="course-listing">
    <a href="#" title="Title1" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Sold Out</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 1</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 1</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$20</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Blue</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 1</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 2</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 3</span>
      </span> 
      </div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    </a> 
        <a href="#" title="Title2" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Available</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 2</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 2</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Orange</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 1</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 2</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 5</span>
      </span> 
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction and also let me know if I am not approaching this in the correct manner? Thank you!

Comment: I do not see any jQuery here. Please at least make an attempt to solve the problem before dumping an assignment onto Stack Overflow

Comment: How do we know where you are having problems if you don't show what you tried. SO is not a free code writing service. The objective here is you show what you tried that didn't work as expected and others help you fix your code...not do all the work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with the following:

I don't fully understand the [0], but it works.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    var i = 0;
 
    while( i <= $('.product-title').length)
  {
 
    var value1 = $(".product-price span")[0];
    var value2 = $(".product-color span")[0];
 
        $(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(' \(', value1, '\,', value2, '\)')
 
  i++;
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="catalog-courses" class="course-listing">
    <a href="#" title="Title1" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Sold Out</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 1</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 1</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$20</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Blue</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 1</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 2</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 3</span>
      </span> 
      </div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    </a> 
        <a href="#" title="Title2" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Available</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 2</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 2</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Orange</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 1</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 2</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 5</span>
      </span> 
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    var i = 0;
  console.log(i);
    while( i <= $('.product-title').length)
  {
 
    var value1 = $(".product-price span")[i];
    var value2 = $(".product-color span")[i];
 
    
  $(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(' \(', value1, '\,', value2, '\)')
  /*$(this).find('.product-title')[i].append(value2);*/
 
  i = i + 1;
  console.log(i);
  }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="catalog-courses" class="course-listing">
    <a href="#" title="Title1" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Sold Out</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 1</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 1</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$20</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Blue</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 1</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 2</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 3</span>
      </span> 
      </div>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    </a> 
        <a href="#" title="Title2" class="container">
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <div class="ribbon">
          <span class="ribbon-text">Available</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Product 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="product-title">Product 2</div>
      <div class="product-description">This is all about product 2</div>
      <div class="product-price">
        <span>$10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-color product-callout">
        <span>Orange</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-tags">
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 1</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 2</span>
      </span> 
      <span class="product-tag" >
        <span>Tag 5</span>
      </span> 
      </div>
    </a>
    </div>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```